# How to include a PDF cleanly in a latex document that uses flowfram?

Tags: pdfpages, flowfram

I have a latex document that uses `flowfram` to define content for all chapters like the following:

```
\usepackage{flowfram}
\newstaticframe[>0]{30pt}{42pt}{-0.5in}{0.961\textheight}[accent1]
\setstaticcontents*{accent1}{\includegraphics[width=42pt,height=9pt,angle=-90]{accent.png}}
% ...more setstaticcontents[>0]

\begin{document}
\chapter{foo}
% ...more chapters
\end{document}
```

How can I include a PDF using `\includepdf` in the latex cleanly without overlapping content? Currently the static frame will flow onto all pages including the included pdf which is not what I want. Maybe modifying the `page list` is one workaround but there's tons of `\newstaticframe[>0]` and I don't want to touch them if there's ways to somehow "reset" or "terminate" the frame?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of " the static frame will flow onto all pages including the included pdf"? not necessarily important. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I can't take a screenshot of it right now but you can think of it as a logo repeating on every page and I want the included page to NOT have that logo. I think I might have found something: `\setstaticframe{all}{clear}` seems to work. Or even better `\setallstaticframes{clear}`

Comment: No. your question was -1 on votes that time, that's why I concerned.